# Problem about argument of Java 8 OptionalInt.of

Tags: java, option-type

1)

`OptionalInt::of` should accept argument int, but why the following can compile?

```
Integer boxed=2;
Optional<OptionalInt> optInt=Optional.ofNullable(boxed).map(OptionalInt::of);
```

`Optional.ofNullable(boxed)` should return `Optional<Integer>`, not int.

2)
why the following cannot compile?

```
Optional.ofNullable(boxed).flatMap(OptionalInt::of);
```

Comment: You can pass an `Integer` where an `int` is required, that’s called autoboxing. But you cannot pass an `OptionalInt` where an `Optional` is required, there is no conversion between these unrelated types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `Optional`'s `map()` requires a mapper `Function` that returns a `? extends U`, so it is allowed to return an `OptionalInt`. Therefore it accepts `OptionalInt::of`. And you can pass an `Integer` to `OptionalInt.of()` due to auto-unboxing.

2) `Optional`'s `flatMap()` requires a mapper `Function` that returns an `Optional<U>`. `OptionalInt` is not an `Optional`, so you can't pass OptionalInt::of to it.

Comment: for 1, Optional.ofNullable(boxed).map(OptionalInt::of), the argument to OptinalInt::of is not Optional<Integer>?

Comment: @user1169587 the argument of `OptionalInt.of()` is `int`, so OptionalInt::of can be used to implement a `Function<Integer,OptionalInt>`, but not a `Function<Integer,Optional<Integer>>`, which is what `flatMap` requires.

Comment: ok, I check the Optional map api again, "If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it", the "it" is the value (Integer), not the container (Optional<Integer>)